# Cannot find some parameters details for this board

Tags: microcontroller, datasheet

I have [this](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00190424-discovery-kit-for-stm32f7-series-with-stm32f746ng-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) micro controller development board and I want to use one of its pin called +5V pin to power a sensor. But I cannot find or figure out the max current this pin can source.
Here below is the highlighted pin in question:

[image]

And also I cannot find the input impedance for the analog inputs.

Comment: Since the board has a 5V power *input*, my assumption is you can draw whatever the actual power source can supply, minus what the board uses, and probably not more than about 1A. How much power does your sensor need?

Comment: I want to power two sensors both requires 10mA.

Comment: You should [edit] both the title and question to include the make and model of the board so that readers don't have to follow a link to understand what you are asking about.

Comment: @ty_1917 That's not a lot of power for this type of board. I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

The current will probably be limited by the traces on the board. See the schematics of the development board: [Schematics](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/ff/cd/ce/2d/f8/fb/40/69/mb1191-F746NGH6-C01_schematic/files/mb1191-F746NGH6-C01_schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.mb1191-F746NGH6-C01_schematic.pdf)

Full documentation is found here, which can be useful to read: [Documents](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/32f746gdiscovery.html#resource)

On sheet 4/14 you will find that the 5V rail is just connected to your 5V input via a jumper. Here is the relevant portion:

[image: jumper selector]

E5V stands for your external power source. If your source can support your required load plus the discovery board itself, there should be no problem.

Comment: If I power the board with the USB port, does that mean the +5V output can source as much as the USB can?

Comment: I think so. 500 mA for common PC USB ports

Answer (score 0):

Audio Input on CN11 has some AC coupled high impedance with 1uF on each input with the WM8994ECS analog input impedance to determine the HPF audio breakpoint.

What is your sensor source impedance and frequency range?